# ReSharper Refactor > Move doesn't work

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a function I want to move to a different object.  In the code, I select the function that I want to move.  I use **ReSharper > Refactor > Move** but nothing happens.

Comment: `Move` is actually very useful.

Comment: Same for me, it's not working

Comment: @Luke see my answer below.  I just added a new option (#1) that you can try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Option 1: Cut and paste

This is a new option I added to the answer.  This is by far the easiest.

1. **Cut** the code you want to move.
2. **Paste** it in the new location.
3. An icon will surface that you can click and choose **Apply Move Refactoring**.

I'm not sure if this option will always work.

## Option 2: Add the object you want to move into as a member

I found that **Refactor > Move** only works if you have that object as a member.  The member must be a concrete type, not an interface.  For example,

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // ReSharper 8.2 will give the option to move to this object only.
    private MyRepository _repo;

    // ...

    public FunctionToMove()
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

It makes sense when you think about it because ReSharper wants to refactor to working code.  You must have a reference to the object in order to call the "moved" method.  Even so, Resharper might consider a different UI decision in this case.  (Like a message)

## Option 3: Change method signature

I was having trouble moving a `private` method to a `static` class.  I changed the method from `private` to `public static` and then I could select the static class I wanted to move it to.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too, while trying to move a file via the ReSharper Refactor menu. Checking the box "To enable Undo, open all files with changes for editing" in the Move dialog fixed the issue.